# Telephone Area code search, Best Match String Comparison

Tags: php, algorithm

If I have a set of tuples `[1, "abc"], [2, "abcd"], [3, "ab"], [4, "abcde"]`.

And a string to search `"ab"`, it should give the best match which is `[3, "ab"]`.

If the string to search is `"abc"`, it should match `[1, "abc"]` since its a more precise match. Similarly, `"abcde"` would match `[4, "abcde"]`.

If the string to search is `"b"` it won't match any tuple. The search always begins from the start of the string.

Is there an algorithm that will return the best match?

I'm doing a telephone area code to location search. The more digits I have the more precisely I can find a location.

Comment: Wanted some pointers towards an algorithm I could use. I'm not sure where to start

Comment: Would `ab` better match `abx` or `aby`???

Comment: What is `best match` according to you?

Comment: If you search on the phrase "string similarity algorithm", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, It shouldn't match anything, since using the telephone code analogy, we won't be able to find a precise area.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, can be worst or best I don't say this is perfect.

You can search `"ab"` in your stored data, and the best result is also should be `[3, "ab"]`, so you can check the length of your key and compare it the results. The equal result should be best.

For `"ab"`, the legnth is `2`. If you can get any search result that also the result's length equal it, that is the best. If you get result which length is `3` so it should be smilar.